# RouterOS push static route for IPSec IKEv2 VPN

Tags: vpn, router, ipsec, static-routes, routeros

Can't find a solution how actually I can push a static routes to VPN clients, when they connect via VPN.

Configuration from [here](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/IPsec#Road_Warrior_setup_using_IKEv2_with_RSA_authentication)

RouterOS, IPSec, IKEv2. Clients mainly macOS users via standard soft.

Any ideas with examples are appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ipsec mode-config is supposed to provide such functionality.

For example if you have the following settings in RouterOS:

> /ip pool add name="ipsec_pool" ranges=192.168.50.2-192.168.50.6
>
> /ip ipsec
> mode-config add name="windows" system-dns=no static-dns=192.168.88.1
> address-pool=ipsec_pool address-prefix-length=29
> split-include=192.168.88.0/24
>
> /ip ipsec peer add address=0.0.0.0/0
> passive=yes auth-method=rsa-signature certificate=ipsec-server-03
> generate-policy=port-strict policy-template-group=win-ikev2
> exchange-mode=ike2 mode-config=windows send-initial-contact=no
> hash-algorithm=sha1 enc-algorithm=aes-256,aes-128
> dh-group=ecp256,ecp384,modp2048,modp1024 lifetime=2h dpd-interval=2m

then RouterOS will assign a virtual ip from the address pool called "ipsec_pool" to the client and tells it to set the DNS server address to 192.168.88.1
(static-dns) and create policies to route all traffic to 192.168.88.0/24 thru IPSec (split-include) tunnel.

However it's up to the client implementation what is going to happen with these mode-config requests. For example: because Windows is setting up a point-to-point VPN connection when using IKEv2, it processes the DNS server setting request but ignores the split-include settings. But it creates a new routing rule to subnet 192.168.50.0/24 regardless what the server is telling.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the IPSec client in MacOS so I cannot help you with that. It might be much more flexible with mode-configs.